# Multiple page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

Im making a article document, my goal is to have all pages with sections using pagenumbering Roman while other pages being in Arabic it would be something like:

Section 1:           I
subsection 1.1    1
Section 2:           II
subsection 2.1    1
subsection 2.2    2
Section 3:           III

Comment: Why? So after each section page numbers shell start with 1 again?

Comment: yes, not sure why its was requested this way

Comment: this sounds crazy. Are you sure that you correctly understood the requirement. E.g. what should happen if a subsection goes over two pages or if there are two subsection on one page?